# can't play video on local area network on ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, avplayer, mpmovieplayercontroller, avplayerviewcontroller

I can play video over web the network but can't over the local area network, my code is bellow.

```
- (IBAction)playAction:(id)sender {
    // cant play
    //self.url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/big_buck_bunny.mp4"];   
    // cant play
    self.url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://192.168.43.1:6080/?methodType=download&path=/Download/hi.mp4"]; 
    AVPlayer *player = [AVPlayer playerWithURL:self.url];
    AVPlayerViewController *playerVC = [[AVPlayerViewController alloc] init];
    playerVC.player = player;
    playerVC.view.frame = self.view.frame;
    [self.view addSubview:playerVC.view];
    self.playerVC = playerVC;
    [self.playerVC.player play];
}
```

Comment: check if you are downloading the video

Comment: not downloading, i check if by Charles, and I find it can be played via chrome but can't via safari.